# Apache2 VirtualHost Error

Tags: javascript, node.js, apache, virtualhost

I have this server with the node application, and it was working perfectly. From night to day it stopped working and now im trying to fix this.

I use apache2 VirtualHost to run this server

VirtualHost code:

```
<VirtualHost *:80 *:443>
   ServerName website.com
   ServerAlias www.website.com

   DocumentRoot /var/www/project
   <Directory /var/www/project>
      Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks
      AllowOverride None
      Require all granted
   </Directory>

   ProxyRequests Off
   ProxyPreserveHost On
   ProxyVia Full
   <Proxy *>
      Require all granted
   </Proxy>

   <Location />
      ProxyPass http://127.0.0.1:3000/
      ProxyPassReverse http://1127.0.0.1:3000/
   </Location>

   ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

   # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
   # alert, emerg.
   LogLevel warn

   CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =www.website.com [OR]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =website.com
RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>
```

My app.js file:

```
var express         = require("express");
var app             = express();

const session       = require('express-session');
const MongoStore    = require('connect-mongo')(session);  

var bodyparser      = require("body-parser"),
mongoose            = require("mongoose"),
passport            = require("passport"),
LocalStrategy       = require("passport-local"),
FacebookStrategy    = require('passport-facebook').Strategy,
TwitterStrategy     = require('passport-twitter').Strategy,
GoogleStrategy      = require('passport-google-oauth').OAuth2Strategy,
expressSanitizer    = require('express-sanitizer'),
methodOverride      = require("method-override"),
flash               = require('connect-flash'),
authData            = require('./auth.js'),
sm                  = require('sitemap'),
fs                  = require('fs');

var User                = require("./models/user");

mongoose.connect("databaselink");

app.use(bodyparser.json());
app.use(bodyparser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(expressSanitizer());
app.set("view engine", "ejs");
app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/public"));
app.use(methodOverride("_method"));
app.use(flash());


// PASSPORT CONFIGURATION
app.use(session({
    cookie : {
        maxAge : 7 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000
    },
    secret: "Bloom blaaaaa bliiiuuuummmmmmm",
    saveUninitialized: false, // don't create session until something stored
    resave: false, //don't save session if unmodified
    store: new MongoStore({ 
        mongooseConnection: mongoose.connection,
        autoRemove: 'native', // Default
        touchAfter: 24 * 3600 // time period in seconds 
    })
}));


app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

passport.use(new LocalStrategy(User.authenticate()));

// used to   serialize the user
passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
        done(null, user.id);
    });

// used to deserialize the user
passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
     User.findById(id, function(err, user) {
        done(err, user);
    });
});


// LISTEN
app.listen("3000", function(){
    console.log("SERVER STARTED");
});
```

What happens:

I was getting the error "EADDRINUSE".

I was using port "8080".
So I searched about the error "EADDRINUSE" and tried changing the port to 3000.

I used FileZilla to update the files in the server.
I added the new app.js file with app.listen(3000) and updated the VirtualHost code.

Then I restarted the apache server and also the pm2 (I use pm2 to keep my node servers online).

But when I try to go to my website i get the following error:

```
Service Unavailable
The server is temporarily unable to service your request due to maintenance downtime or capacity problems. Please try again later.

Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) Server at www.website.com Port 80
```

I tried to run node app.js separated from pm2 and got this error:

```
error listen EADDRINUSE :::3000
```

I used killall node but it says that there is no node process.

So I restarted the VPN:

After restarting the VPN i used node app.js again and it worked very well.
Then I used pm2 start app.js and it also worked very well. But I still can't access the website without the VirtualHost

So I start the apache/VirtualHost and the problems start all again.

The problem is with the VirtualHost code? How can I fix this?

Comment: Are you on linux?  Do you have access to the command line on the box you are running this on? I know that you are using Filezilla to update the files.  If you do have access, try running `netstat -tulpn | grep 3000` to see what program is listening on that port (3000).  It could very well be that pm2 is running multiple instances of your node app on the same box, and the first instance binds to 3000, and the second gets the EADDRINUSE.   Of course, since this worked before, that might not be the case.  Can you confirm pm2 is actually working? There was a recent update that broke things.

Comment: Link to the issue about pm2 recently breaking because of pidusage: https://github.com/Unitech/pm2/issues/3827

Comment: @Morfie Hello, used the command `netstat -tulpn | grep 3000` and it showed one instance of _app.js_ running on port 3000. I deleted the app.js instace from pm2 and now i can run _node app.js_. So the problem really is with pm2. Any idea on how i can fix pm2? Or something else to use in place of pm2? Thank You

Comment: What version of pm2 are you running?  I was using 3.0.1 and I got issues.  I downgraded to 2.10.4 and it fixed all my issues.

Comment: They just (2 seconds ago) updated PM2 to 3.0.2. You can try that as well, as that update was specifically to fix this problem.

Comment: @Morfie Just installed PM2 3.0.2, run `netstat -tulpn | grep 3000` and its only one instance of _app.js_. I restarted apache2, but now when i access the website I got this error `The proxy server received an invalid response from an upstream server.
The proxy server could not handle the request GET /index.

Reason: Error reading from remote server

Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) Server at www.listsroll.com Port 80`

Comment: @Morfie I remember i already got this error when I was setting up the website, I believe the problem is with the VirtualHost code?

Comment: @Morfie Hey, the website is working now, im only having a problem with mongoDB but i can fix that, thank you very much for the help :)

Comment: Was it PM2 or something else?

Comment: @Morfie I updated PM2 and it works now, the problem that I was having after updating PM2 was with mongoDB. Everything is fine now ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main issue was that pm2 was breaking.  One of the library's dependencies (pidusage) broke pm2.  (Reference: https://github.com/Unitech/pm2/issues/3827)
This was fixed in the next version of pm2 (3.0.2).

This caused a lot of problems in a lot of projects, as pm2 is widely used.